# Add control flow in SQL server Merge statement

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, merge

I am doing a MERGE statement in SQL Server 2008 R2. What I want to do is to have a more logic inside a NOT MATCHED branch:

```
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (col1, col2, col3) 
    VALUES (SOURCE.col1, SOURCE.col2, SOURCE.col3)
        OUTPUT INSERTED.col1, SOURCE.col4
    INTO @Mapping

    INSERT INTO @newChildren
    (   col1,
    other columns,) 
    SELECT 
    (   TARGET.col1, 
    other columns)
        FROM @input 
        INNER JOIN @Mapping 
        ON @input.col1 = @Mapping.col2

    EXECUTE Children_Create @newChildren;
```

The idea is to do use INSERT result to form another input to another stored procedure. But it seems control flow is not supported in SQL Server 2008 MERGE. I can't put BEGIN/END to wrap this code. Any suggestions to overcome this limit?

Comment: i don't believe you can: thats the way the syntax is defined.

Comment: So I guess I have to break the procedure to two, one for update and one for insert...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` keywords being parts of `MERGE` might have led you into thinking that `MERGE` is a sort of compound statement. But it is only a *complex* one. The above-mentioned keywords introduce *clauses* of `MERGE`, not separate corresponding statements, however much they may resemble the latter.

So yes, if not as a separate procedure, yet at least outside `MERGE` is how your additional inserts must be implemented.